# Как создать свою локальную базу данных C#

Tags: c#

Условно задача такая: есть паллет, в нем гофрокороба, а в каждом из них находятся упаковки с лекарствами. Информацию с производства этих паллет надо хранить в моей базе данных. На мой сервер поступает информация об этих паллетах в виде Xml дерева со всеми вложенностями (у каждой паллеты есть свой уникальный номер, у каждого вложенного гофрокороба есть тоже свой уникальный номер). Я до этого хранил этот Xml дерево просто в виде строки в текстовом файле, что занимало много места.

**У меня вопрос: как лучше хранить эти данные в меньшем объеме? Мне подсказали надо создать свою базу данных, с сохранением вложенностей. Может Excel или создать свои таблицы в файлах например?**

Comment: *"Просто в виде строки в текстовом файле, что занимало много места"* - для начала можно включить NTFS сжатие в папке. И скорость доступа вырастет и занимаемый объем сократиться. Далее можете архивировать исторические данные (например, все что старше 45дней).

Comment: Такое мне не подходит

Comment: Тогда уточните, какое вам *"подходит"* и почему. Т.к. одно дело решения конкретной ситуации (вариантов много и разных, в т.ч. не программных), а другое - выполнение чужого расплывчатого задания *"создать свою БД"*. Так то, и папка с файлами - это БД.

Comment: что-то наподобие bdForge Studio for MySQL

Comment: А с вот этим просто ищите туториалы и примеры проектов, там вам ВСЁ расскажут для начала )

Comment: dbForge Studio это не БД, это СУБД.

Comment: Какие операции будут осуществляться с этими данными, с этой БД? Поиск? Редактирование? Вставка? Удаление? Есть ли сложносвязанные данные? Нужен ли по ним быстрый поиск (ака индексы)? Каков объём данных? В зависимости от ответов на эти вопросы и следует подбирать нужную СУБД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно подумать, какая информация в XML лишняя. Очевидно, что XML содержит не только полезную информацию, но и описание её структуры. Это - первый кандидат на оптимизацию. Если структура данных постоянная или есть несколько постоянных структур, то её (их) нужно сохранить отдельно или даже можно сделать это в коде программы, а из сохраняемых данных исключить.

Второй кандидат на оптимизацию - это постоянные строковые значения, которые можно заменить числами. Здесь даже необязательно знать заранее все значения - встретил новое и добавил его в словарь.

Третий способ оптимизации - хранение данных в бинарном виде. Например, даты, числа. Это значительно экономит место и избавляет от проблем с локализацией и т. п.